# JavaFX: How to remember scroll location of tabcontent after refreshing content ?

Tags: java, javafx, treeview

I am implmenting a file browser using treeview in JavaFX. And i set the treeview in Tab as conent. As i refresh elements of treeview using scheduled threads, i am unable to scroll to previously selected tree item. Here is the minimal version of my implmentation.

```
 /**
 *
 * @author nika
 */
public class TabTreeView extends Application implements Runnable {

private TreeItem<String> root;
private TreeView<String> tv = new TreeView<>();
private static ArrayList<NumberPair> rememberExpanded = new ArrayList<>();
private TreeItem<String> previouslySelectedTreeItem;

@Override
public void run() {
    root = new TreeItem<>("Root");
    root.setExpanded(true);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        TreeItem<String> sublevel = new TreeItem<>("Level : " + i + " TS: " + System.currentTimeMillis());
        final int level = i;
        if (rememberExpanded.contains(new NumberPair(level, -9999))) {
            sublevel.setExpanded(true);
        }
        sublevel.expandedProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observable, Boolean oldValue, Boolean newValue) {
                if (newValue) {
                    rememberExpanded.add(new NumberPair(level, -9999));
                } else {
                    rememberExpanded.remove(new NumberPair(level, -9999));
                }
            }
        });
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            TreeItem<String> subsublevel = new TreeItem<>("SubLevel : " + j + " @ " + i + " TS:" + System.currentTimeMillis());
            final int level2 = j;
            if (rememberExpanded.contains(new NumberPair(level, level2))) {
                sublevel.setExpanded(true);
            }
            subsublevel.expandedProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {
                @Override
                public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observable, Boolean oldValue, Boolean newValue) {
                    if (newValue) {
                        rememberExpanded.add(new NumberPair(level, level2));
                    } else {
                        rememberExpanded.remove(new NumberPair(level, level2));
                    }
                }
            });

            sublevel.getChildren().add(subsublevel);
        }
        root.getChildren().add(sublevel);
    }
    Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            tv.setRoot(root);
            //scroll to previously selected item
            //i know this one is wrong 1. "as it is not working", 2. "because it will only look into children of root not grandchildren".
            tv.scrollTo(root.getChildren().indexOf(previouslySelectedTreeItem));
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    TabPane tabpane = new TabPane();
    tv.selectionModelProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<MultipleSelectionModel<TreeItem<String>>>() {
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends MultipleSelectionModel<TreeItem<String>>> observable, MultipleSelectionModel<TreeItem<String>> oldValue, MultipleSelectionModel<TreeItem<String>> newValue) {
            previouslySelectedTreeItem = newValue.getSelectedItem();
        }
    });
    Tab t = new Tab("Demo", tv);
    tabpane.getTabs().add(t);
    BorderPane bp = new BorderPane(tabpane);
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(bp));
    primaryStage.show();
    ScheduledExecutorService exc = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
    exc.scheduleAtFixedRate(this, 0, 2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    launch(TabTreeView.class, args);

}

private class NumberPair {

    int first, second;

    public NumberPair(int first, int second) {
        this.first = first;
        this.second = second;
    }

    public int getFirst() {
        return first;
    }

    public void setFirst(int first) {
        this.first = first;
    }

    public int getSecond() {
        return second;
    }

    public void setSecond(int second) {
        this.second = second;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 3;
        hash = 37 * hash + this.first;
        hash = 37 * hash + this.second;
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) {
            return true;
        }
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        final NumberPair other = (NumberPair) obj;
        if (this.first != other.first) {
            return false;
        }
        if (this.second != other.second) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "NumberPair{" + "first=" + first + ", second=" + second + '}';
    }

}

}
```

Is there anyway to remember to scroll location of tabcontent or treeview? So that i can restore the scroll position after refreshing the view.

In this implementation i have added a `NumberPair` class to remember expanded items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find ScrollBar reference of TreeView by styleclass. Try this.

```
Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        double position[] = new double[]{0.0d};
        Optional<ScrollBar> scroll = findScrollBar(tv, Orientation.VERTICAL);
        scroll.ifPresent(s -> position[0] = s.getValue());
        tv.setRoot(root);
        scroll.ifPresent(s -> s.setValue(position[0]));
    }
});

private Optional<ScrollBar> findScrollBar(TreeView<String> from, Orientation orientation) {
    Set<Node> nodes = from.lookupAll(".scroll-bar");
    return nodes.stream()
            .filter(node -> node instanceof ScrollBar && ((ScrollBar)node).getOrientation() == orientation)
            .map(node -> ((ScrollBar)node))
            .findFirst();
}
```

But note that, trying to keep same items in TreeItem might be good approach. TreeView is desiened to keep selections expansions and scroll position as long as you add and remove items from unique root.